# Changing imageview is drawing ontop on old image

Tags: java, android

I have a default image set as a src for an ImageView. Then i want to change this image. I do this:

```
ImageView imageView;
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dude);
```

The result is that it only puts itself ontop of the old one, why could that be?

EDIT: added the xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="241dp"
    android:layout_height="214dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/car"
    android:src="@drawable/car" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="clickclick"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="clickclick"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="clickclick"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="clickclick"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/instructionsGame"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove android:background="@drawable/car".  The background and image source are two different attributes.

Comment: @A--C:  indeed i should do that.. works fine now :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ImageView` height/width to `WRAP_CONTEN`T and remove `android:background="@drawable/car"` from ImageButton background :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    android:src="@drawable/car" />
```